# How to get no results in Excel If function if there's no match

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

[image]

Hello I've rows of data with Emp ID, dates and time.

I need the find the earliest time of specific person by his Emp ID on a specific day.

This is the formula that I've using. It gets me the correct data, but when there's no match, its gives me the date "Jan 1, 1990". Can anyone help me correct it?

```
=MIN(IF(DATA!A:A='Report '!B4,(IF(DATA!B:B='Report '!$D$1,DATA!C:C))))
```

Comment: Try this `=MIN(IF((DATA!A:A='Report '!B4)*(DATA!B:B='Report '!$D$1),DATA!C:C,""))` and set the format of the cells as `mmm dd, yyyy;;`

Comment: Better option: `=AGGREGATE(15,6,DATA!C:C/((DATA!A:A='Report '!B4)*(DATA!B:B='Report '!$D$1)),1)` .

Comment: What is your Excel version?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Hello, yes AGGREGATE function works better. Thanks. Could you also please suggest the function that will find the latest time on that day for that person.

Comment: Hi @ForhadZaman just posted in answers, also posted another way of getting both earliest and latest time with one formula using `AGGREGATE()` Function

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try using the following formulas as mentioned above in my comments:

[image]

---

**For Earliest Time:**

• Formula used in cell `F4`

```
=MIN(IF(($A:$A=$F$2)*($B:$B=$F3),$C:$C,""))
```

Or,

• Formula used in cell `F5`

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$C:$C/(($A:$A=$F2)*($B:$B=$F3)),1),"")
```

---

**For Latest Time:**

• Formula used in cell `F6`

```
=MAX(IF(($A:$A=$F$2)*($B:$B=$F3),$C:$C,""))
```

Or,

• Formula used in cell `F7`

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,$C:$C/(($A:$A=$F2)*($B:$B=$F3)),1),"")
```

---

**Bonus Trick: Both Earliest & Latest Time with one formula**

• Formula used in cell `E13`

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE({15,14},6,$C:$C/(($A:$A=$F2)*($B:$B=$F3)),1),"")
```

---

**Note:** Kindly change the range as per your suit, also based on `Excel Version`, one may need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Assume your data looks like this and you want like that.

here is the formula you can apply.
=IFERROR(MIN(FILTER($C$3:$C$99,($A$3:$A$99=$F3)*($B$3:$B$99=G$2),"Not Found")),"Not Found")

You can use Minifs and Maxifs as well but if not found it will return zero and zero is in time format will show 12:00 am.
=MINIFS(C:C,A:A,F3,B:B,G2)

[image]